# given vectors how do you determine if it is in subspace

Tags: linear-algebra

I have no idea how to even attempt this question. I tried looking it up but I still did not understand. If you could dumb it down and explain it to me I would appreciate it a lot Thanks in advance.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

The basic checklist to be sure that $F$ is a subspace of the $\mathbb{K}$-vector space $E$ is as follows:

- $F\subset E$
- $F$ is a vector space, that is $\forall (\lambda, \mu) \in \mathbb{K}^2, \forall  (u,v)\in F^2, \lambda u + \mu v \in F$

It all narrows down to what Mohammad Riazi-Kermani said but maybe it is a bit more "dumbed down".

Comment: thanks for the comment, but Im not sure what just happened.

Comment: Maybe an example would be easier to understand: consider (a), the set to consider made of vectors (-t,2t) is clearly a subset of $\mathbb{R}^2$. All that is left to check is whether or not linear combinations of any two elements of the set are still in the set. Do you see how you could get through?

Answer (score 0):

In order for a non-empty subset of a vector space to be a subspace,you need closure under addition and scalar multiplication.

In your problem only parts $a$ and $d$ satisfy  these two conditions.

Check $b$ and $c$ carefully to see why they fail to be a subspace.

Comment: Hi, thank you for the help. I dont really understand what closure under addition and scalar multiplication means. Not sure if related, but for example, for a) making t = 0?

Comment: it means if you add two vectors from the subspace, the result must be in the subspace. Similarly if your multiply a vector by a number, the result is in the subspace.